# How to adjust siri's volume so it will sound louder via earpod?

Tags: siri, iphone

This happens lately and I don't know how to fix it.

When I  listen to podcast  using the app 'cast' with my earpod, from time to time I long press the remote to ask for some information. Let's say the volume of the podcast output is at 8 (out of 10), the siri answer will out very weak and feels like it is set to 1 or 2.

I have tried increasing the volume when siri is activated but it does not have any effect.

Is there anything I can do to increase siri's volume?

**EDIT** Add model and version info

The iphone is 6s (NKQN2ZP/A)

OS version is 10.2.1

Comment: Siri's volume can be adjusted on your iPhone's volume rocker while Siri is talking on your iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siri has an independent volume. When Siri is talking, use the volume buttons on your iPhone to change the volume of Siri. This is preserved for next time Siri is used.

Comment: It would be nice if it can be controlled via the vol controls on the remote of the earpod.

Comment: @AnthonyKong That should work too, does it not?